# Keras Binary Classifier Tutorial Example gives only 50% validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Keras Binary Classifier Tutorial Example gives only 50% validation accuracy.
The near 50% accuracy can be gotten from an un-trained classifier itself for binary classification.

This example is straight from https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow_core.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

np.random.seed(10)

# Generate dummy data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, 20))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))

x_test = np.random.random((800, 20))
y_test = np.random.randint(2, size=(800, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=50,
          batch_size=128,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

Accuracy output.

- I tried with multiple trials.
- Increased the number of hidden layers

> Epoch 50/50 1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s
>   211us/sample - loss: 0.6905 - accuracy: 0.5410 - val_loss: 0.6959 -
>   val_accuracy: 0.4812

Could someone help me understand if anything is wrong here?

- How to increase the accuracy for this "example" problem presented in the tutorial?

Comment: Um, so what exactly are you trying? Fitting random data with a model?  Well if that's the case, of course you'll get 50% accuracy (for a binary classification problem) (unless you overfit the model - in which case you'll get close to 100% accuracy on training data).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yeah, I realize my mistake. I was taking the example from the tutorial and I got mislead by the random picking up of the test data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you train a classifier with `random` examples, you will always get aprrox. 50% accuracy at **validation** data here represented by `x_test`. It is because your training samples get trained with random classes. Also the validation or test set has been assigned to random classes. This is why the random accuracy i.e. 50-50% occurs.
The more epoch you test the training set the more accuracy you will get on **training** set as an effect of **[overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)**.

Comment: Thanks! This helps explain my problem. I tried to evaluate the model on `X_train` - the data against which I trained. But still the accuracy was around 60% and it is confusing me. For simple binary classifier with the data of 1000s. Training and testing on same data should give 100% accuracy.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran You're welcome! What I'm seeing, that you validated and evaluated on X_test not on X_train, which you trained your model against. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SenthilKumaran If you evaluate your model on training set the accuracy will get better the more epoch you train. As it is total a random dataset, with no actual pattern, this process will take a bit longer, so simply increase the epoch number.

Comment: yeah, that was correct. I had to have a very very high value for epochs for my training to fit my 'training data' itself properly.